# CSS Transition Effect In Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, accordion, transition

I'm trying to make an accordion with CSS.
The transition (when mouse over) works well in Chrome and Opera. But there's no transition for Firefox,

below is the part of CSS with the problem.

```
   transition : height 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.9s ease-in        -out;
   -o-transition: height 0.9 ease-in-out;
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
transition: height 0.9s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Open this Fiddle in firefox -  http://jsfiddle.net/TBMcW/1/
Is it working? Cause its working here.